# Get arbitrary resources content in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I need to get the content of the resources received in command line. The user can write a relative path to a file or an URL. Is it possible to read from this resource regardless if it is a path to a file or an URL?

In Ruby I have something like the next, but I'm having problems finding a Python alternative:

```
content = open(path_or_url) { |io| io.read }
```

Comment: What do you mean `independently`?

Comment: @laike9m Regardless of the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a nice way to do it, however, `urllib.request.urlopen()` will support opening normal URLs (http, https, ftp, etc) as well as files on the file system. So you could assume a file if the URL is missing a scheme component:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.request import urlopen

resource = input('Enter a URL or relative file path: ')
if urlparse(resource).scheme == '':
    # assume that it is a file, use "file:" scheme
    resource = 'file:{}'.format(resource)
data = urlopen(resource).read()
```

This works for the following user input:

```
http://www.blah.com
file:///tmp/x/blah
file:/tmp/x/blah
file:x/blah     # assuming cwd is /tmp
/tmp/x/blah
x/blah          # assuming cwd is /tmp
```

Note that `file:` (without slashes) might not be a valid URI, however, this is the only way to open a file specified by *relative* path, and `urlopen()` works with such URIs.

Comment: Works like a charm and is actually a quite good solution. Thank you.